# Rust on Leopard

Tags: haxe, rust

I have tried the macport for rust and it failed. How do I compile rust on leopard, if I can run mono ( and mono develop ) and make haxe on leopard then it must be possible to use rust. I have gcc 4.6 so fairly recent compiler setup.

I am interested to try rust and now that the an early haxe-rust port is out even more interested.  I can open my pc but to be honest I always end up experimenting on my mac so unless I can install it on this leopard system I doubt I will explore it properly.  Any tips on make ing rust appreciated.

And looking at the mailing list it suggests that even if I upgraded I would currently have issues with running rust on a mac.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it yourself? (e.g. from [the 0.6 tarball](http://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-0.6.tar.gz) or from git?)

Comment: relevant tracker issue : https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/4232

Comment: `Any tips on makeing rust appreciated`. Take iron + water + time ;)

Comment: extracting rust-stage0/lib/librustllvm.dylib
compile: rt/x86_64-apple-darwin/sync/timer.o
g++: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized option '-arch'
make: *** [rt/x86_64-apple-darwin/sync/timer.o] Error 1
JustinComputer:rust-0.6 justinmills$ rust

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately as far as Leopard support, nobody has stepped up to provide the backporting effort; the mozilla-employed core developers are targeting newer OSX variants at this point, so it's up to volunteers to maintain other variants, best-effort. We only have so much time.